# Why is $\int |e^{ix}|^2 dx = x + C$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, complex-numbers

Quick question:
Wolfram Alpha tells me that

$$\int |e^{ix}|^2 dx = x + C$$

Why is that?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because $$|e^{ix}|=1$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: *facepalm* - should have seen that, too. Thank you very much!